# How can I remove rows that break periodicity with a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, row-number

I have a table as below. There is not periodicity between data so i couldn't use functions like row_number() or rank.

```
**Column1**  |  **Column2**  |  **Timestamp**
Station1     |  Data1        | Date1    
Station1     |  Data2        | Date2
Station1     |  Data1        | Date3
Station1     |  Data2        | Date4
Station1     |  **Data3**    | Date5
Station1     |  Data2        | Date6
Station2     |  Data1        | Date7
Station2     |  Data2        | Date8
Station2     |  **Data3**    | Date9
Station2     |  Data2        | Date10
```

Normal data in column2 was like Data1 and Data2, but when it inserted Data3 to column2, it broke the periodicity between Data1 and Data2. I don't want to see data retrieving in my query from after Data3. I want it to be like below.

```
**Column1**  |  **Column2**  |  **Timestamp**
Station1     |  Data1        | Date1    
Station1     |  Data2        | Date2
Station1     |  Data1        | Date3
Station1     |  Data2        | Date4
Station2     |  Data1        | Date7
Station2     |  Data2        | Date8
```

What can I do to reach to this result? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want "data1" only if the next row is "data2" and "data2" only if the previous row is "data1".  So:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(column2) over (partition by column1 order by timestamp) as prev_column2,
             lead(column2) over (partition by column1 order by timestamp) as next_column2
      from t
     ) t
where (column2 = 'data1' and next_column2 = 'data2') or
      (column2 = 'data1' and prev_column2 = 'data1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to show Data1 and Data2 rows, but only those where the previous such row was the other data. In other words you want to show the alternating Data1 and Data2 rows. This can be achieved with `LAST_VALUE`:

```
select column1, column2, timestmp
from
(
  select 
    column1, column2, timestmp,
    last_value(case when column2 in ('Data1', 'Data2') then column2 end ignore nulls)
     over
      (order by timestmp rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as last_col2
  from mytable
)
where column2 in ('Data1', 'Data2')
and decode(column2, last_col2, 'same', 'different') = 'different'
order by timestmp;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8611e24eb0d54ba65e89391d11332cd

(If it is granted, however, that there is always the Data3 row plus the one following row to remove, then you can use `LAG` instead and dismiss all rows where `column2 = '**Data3**' or lag(column2) = '**Data3**'`.)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified format:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7fa37/11)

```
SELECT X.column1, x.column2, x.timestamp FROM 
(
SELECT A.*, LEAD(COLUMN2) OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN1, column2) NEXT_VALUE
FROM TABLE1 A
) X WHERE 'Data3' not IN (COLUMN2, NEXT_VALUE) 
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```